Which quadric surface is formed by $z^2 = xy$?
(Based on a statement of V. Arnold):

Which quadric surface is formed by $z^2 = xy$?

As a nondegenerate, nonimaginary degree 2 equation in $\mathbb R ^3$, this must be a quadric surface.  I believe it is a cone, but am having trouble visualizing (or proving) this. Graphing it in Desmos 3D looks very different than a cone, but I believe that's simply an artifact of the bounding boxes being in the $x,y,z$ planes.

For a big hint, you could try rotating it 45 degrees about the $z$-axis using the substitutions $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x'-y')$, $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x'+y')$, $z = z'$, and then see what the quadric becomes in the $x',y',z'$ coordinates.

@DanielSchepler Thanks.  I recognized the need to rotate, but didn't know how to do so.  How did you derive those substitutions?

"(Based on a statement of V. Arnold)" : could you give the reference ?

@JeanMarie https://www.math.fsu.edu/~wxm/Arnold.htm

@SRobertjames Thanks : Very interesting text !

The given surface $(S)$ is a cone because its equation is homogeneous : if $(X,Y,Z)$ belongs to $(S)$, then $(aX,aY,aZ)$ belongs to $(S)$ for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$. It is interesting to plot it :

This figure displays elliptical sections by planes $(P) : x+y=2$ and $(P') : x+y=-2$ ; in particular, the ellipse which is obtained with plane $(P)$ is parameterized in the following way :
$$(x,y,z)=(2\cos(t)^2,2\sin(t)^2,\sin(2t))$$
(due to trigonometry formula $\sin(2t)=2\sin(t)\cos(t)$);
See the details on the SAGE program below which has generated the figure.
 var('t L')
 fx(t)=2*cos(t)^2
 fy(t)=2*sin(t)^2
 fz(t)=sin(2*t)
 #L=2.5;g=implicit_plot3d(z^2-x*y,(x,-L,L),(y,-L,L),(z,-L,L),opacity=0.5)
 g=parametric_plot3d((fx(t),fy(t),fz(t)), (-pi/2,pi/2),color='red',aspect_ratio=1)
 g+=parametric_plot3d((-fx(t),-fy(t),-fz(t)), (-pi/2,pi/2),color='red')
 for k in range(-50,50) :
    t=k*pi/100
    g+=line3d([(fx(t),fy(t),fz(t)),(-fx(t),-fy(t),-fz(t))],color='blue')
 show(g)


Live demo: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFkc1ugzAQhO9%2DCks9YJM1IURcUvkNOPZWNZFrjGPxY8s4LfD0lSHcIvWymh2tvhlpf4QnScBVQhFqJhIoL1JpRxLotUDNvBmjGZ7GEo24Fmmg6K3iRVa%2Da2561xlpws11NpxrslwLNqUzkAlYBRUFMu9ieQrrhDRh5nlWUoQ0d8KLXgVv5A4hax9YS8CaTAET5syxgDgoSNtZzxOv6gTE6JQMNy%2DCsfxEkT68QrKNyTYo%2D49KUWM9brEZsBeDVoSVOZQ5xReEMcaBt6kzx1Oer6s%2D8M4M6lyTz1fdX4d%5F7Xnf3UPFL%2DhsvNtf0sTu%5FMM%5FFOBwV73iSS18Gy%5F%2DALyygJ0=&lang=sage

@PM 2Ring Good idea. Thanks !

@PM2Ring The live demo doesn't look like the image in the answer?

@SRobertJames That version has the translucent implicit function commented out. Try this one: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFkcFuhCAURfcm_gM7wD6sw8RNJ_yBy9k1nQlVdIiOEGRa9euLWnfTlAW57ybvnkv4ko5gjwo0ognNmMZRHNUj8VTwpDRDEBcenGlzBt3vzrw4y8wTH7YKwdP81Ah9t50utb_azvhjReYLZ2MyARmBFVBQINMu5l9hrAwLk8jSfMU3L8JKJ-_KO13uOWQtBWsRWOEUEGFWv3JYLgql6YwT2KkKgxysKv3VSa-NONC_MtkWyrZU9l9syKmNQy3SPXKybxRheQZ5RtFbHKFwvGiTsHXIsm0O1E73KqDen_V_zv_YkZ_dQ20f0qTDzXyTenmAOLuHAuRvKmhcSddi-gNY0YMF&lang=sage

@PM2Ring Still doesn't look like it (and, at least to me, isn't recognizable.)

@SRobertJames That's weird. It's a double elliptical cone, with the two cones meeting at their vertices, bounded by a cube. It's identical to Jean Marie's image, except I changed the theme from 'light' to 'dark'.
